# How can list local file using lftp

Tags: lftp

I'am on Ubuntu 19.10 and using lftp 4.8.4

from lftp help, I see, I can use bash command using '!'

I like to list my local file: not remote!
`ls` list remote file
`!ls`, `!dir`, `!dir` list remote file too 
`lls` **unknown command**

`lpwd` give me current local path but I like to list local file too!
Have I to open a new terminal to list local file?

Can you help?
best regards,
Leonardo

**P.S.** On man page I read:

> ```
>   !ls
>   To do a directory listing of the local host.
> ```

but not work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have get a answer from other channel:
the right command is:  `local ls`
the `!ls` is wrong